# How to view html file without browser, e.g. on HPC

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I made a website and I have all the html, css, and js files in a folder. I can open the file in chrome, but I was wondering if there was a way to open and view html files without using a browser, maybe like an app that acts as a browser but is offline and only opens .html files.
One use case is opening files on a high performance computing cluster with no internet access and no browsers installed. Using secure copy to bring very large .html files onto a personal computer for hundreds of samples would be very time consuming and require manual input. A way to view text and images of an .html file without a browser would be very useful if it exists.
Thank you!

Comment: HTML files are meant to be opened in a browser. There are desktop alternatives but they all just use browser engines to render HTML. What's your use case?

Comment: "... if ... this question is vague" Yes, it is. E.g. you can view HTML files in text editor..

Comment: Basically, every time you open HTML (not a code, but the actual DOM which is created once it's read) you need a browser to read it. When the app opens it, it usually uses a built-in browser or has something similar to a browser core inside the actual source code of itself. You might also be able to write your own "HTML reader" but it's so much work and it's practically reinventing the wheel.

Comment: So the big question is why wouldn't you want to use a browser?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

HTML is made for browsers. You can't run scripts made for browsers without a browser.